# Creating UDF with more than 10 arguments

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a DataFrame that has a nested structure. So first I create the DataFrame with all the columns (even the ones that are going to be included in the nested structure.)

```
var df = spark.read.text(inputFile)
        .select(substring(col("value"), 41, 1).alias("carrier"), substring(col("value"), 42, 1).alias("currency"),
          substring(col("value"), 43, 3).alias("amount"), substring(col("value"), 46, 3).alias("country"),
          substring(col("value"), 49, 4).alias("code"), substring(col("value"), 53, 8).alias("quantity"),.......)
```

I then have a case class specifying the columns inside the nested structure:

```
  case class temp(currency: String, amount: String, country: String, code: String, quantity: String,....)
```

Then I create the UDF

```
  val makeStruct = udf((currency: String, amount: String, country: String, code: String, quantity: String,....) => temp(currency, amount, country, code, quantity,....))
```

and finally the resulting DataFrame

```
df = df.withColumn("segments", makeStruct(col("currency"), col("amount"), col("country"), col("code"),
        col("quantity"),....)))
        .drop("currency", "amount", "country", "code", "quantity",...)
```

This works perfectly if I had less than 10 arguments in my UDF, however, I don't. How can I make it so that I have a DataFrame with the nested structure that I want, where the UDF can take more than 10 arguments?

Comment: You don't need UDF for creating structs, Spark has `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct` function for creating the structs.

Comment: @vindev Hmm, how would I specify what type they are (String, Integer, etc.)?

Comment: The type will be your column type. You can change column types using `cast` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all of your required columns as an array with `functions.array`

For example, I have the following udf:

```
  val myUdf = functions.udf((r: mutable.WrappedArray[_])=> {
    // You can have access to your data via `r` with the order 
    true // a test value
  })
```

So you can pass your columns into your udf as the following example

```
df.groupBy(df("id"),df("code"))
    .agg(count(myUdf(array(df("country"),df("city"),df("district")))))
    .show(10)
```

As the above example, I put all 3 columns into 1 single array: country, city, district. Then pass it into my udf.